# Node.js preresponse with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, response

So I'm doing a web page with Node.js and Express framework. I already have registration and login (I'm holding users id in a session). Next step is to render different page whenever a user is authenticated.

Some of those pages require a `User` object which is just a mapping of a user from my db. So whenever an authenticated request comes I need to retrieve the user from my db. But writing this code every time seems to be a bad way to do this. So here's the question: is it possible (and if it, then how?) to do, say preresponse, so I can automaticaly retrieve `User` object whenever I know that the user is authenticated and THEN do the main response?

Comment: Can't you just store the `User` object in the session?

Comment: Not really, because the content may change and I want to be sure, that every time I make response I have the correct data. Hmm, but perhaps you're right. Maybe I should redesign it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Middleware is what you are referring to. Middleware is just a function that gets called sequentially when the route is triggered. So to have a loadUser function:

```
function loadUser(req, res, next) {
  // You would fetch your user from the db
  var user = users[req.params.id];
  if (user) {
    req.user = user;
    next();
  } else {
    next(new Error('Failed to load user ' + req.params.id));
  }
}

app.get('/user/:id', loadUser, function(req, res){
  res.send('Viewing user ' + req.user.name);
});
```

You can define as many middleware functions as your need. Just be sure to call next() at the end to pass the route handling on to the next function.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you very much! This is exactly what I need! As Peter Lyons mentioned this is all covered in Express documentation. I looked there but I have no idea why I missed it. :) Thanks again! I marked your answer, because Peter Lyons has more points. :)

Answer (score 1):

This EXACT example is covered in the [express.js route middleware docs](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#route-middleware).  Go read it and you'll see the pattern of using middleware to factor out common functionality that you need at many route paths in your app.